# Вывод строки без использования массива

Tags: c

Привет!

Ввожу номер месяца, номер 1 - и это январь(у меня просто символ 'y'). Как можно вывести полностью строку Yanvar без использования массива?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m1;
    char c;
    scanf("%d", &m1);
    c = m1 == 1 ? 'y' : m1 == 2 ? 'f' : m1 == 3 ? 'm' : 'o';
    printf("%d -> %cn", m1, c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* month = "Yanvar";
printf("%s", month);
```

Comment: accept! =)

Comment: @marioxxx, но учтите, что month это **массив**. Просто он так синтаксически замаскирован. Обычно такие массивы называют *строковыми константами*.

Интересно, как в оригинале (полностью) выглядело Ваше задание ? Не сочтите за труд, опубликуйте.

Comment: month это указатель на массив

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно без массива строк, то тупо через разветвитель

```
switch (m1) {
  case (1) : {puts ("January"); break;}
  case (2) : .......
...........
  default: { puts ("Wrong number"); break;}
}
```

Comment: Точно, автор видимо что-то такое хотел. Можно еще вместо puts() устанавливать указатель на название месяца, а печатать после switch.

Comment: Тоже можно. Может немного уменьшить размер файла.

Comment: case тоже вариант. 
вместо puts как использовать указатель?

Comment: Чё? ))))))

Comment: avp "Можно еще вместо puts() устанавливать указатель на название месяца, а печатать после switch." Как реализовать?

Comment: Например так

    char *p;
    switch (m1) {
      case 1:
         p = "Jan"; break;
      case 2:
         p = "Feb"; break;
      ......
      default:
         p = "???";
    }
    puts(p);

Не очень то срочно Вам ответы понадобились.

Comment: аа понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Выводим посимвольно вызовом puthchar():

```
void main() {
    putchar('Y');
    putchar('a');
    putchar('n');
    putchar('v');
    putchar('a');
    putchar('r');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: а остальными месяцами что?)